# not in %in% function for adding suffix to columns of a data frames from 2 other dataframes

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I need to add the suffix to column names based on the names from two other data frames as "UN" if it is not there.
the data frame looks like,

```
head(df)

AE02    AE03    AE04    AE05    AE06    AE07    AE08    AE09    AE10    AE11    AE12
11.9619362364   18.5701402709   42.2010838789   28.0025053738   19.5589170223   18.1459582989   16.5292369479   32.4885640738   34.0342144643   31.6971000153   44.932255488
2.9904840591    3.9793157723    0   0   1.7780833657    1.7281865047    13.7743641233   4.3318085432    0   17.067669239    0
0   0   0   0   2.6671250485    0   4.5914547078    0   0   0   2.1396312137
```

and the other datafrme

```
head(phlike)
 V1
AE06
AE08    
AE09
AE12
```

And the DMR data frame is a of different length same format

Here is what I tried, I created a function as not in

```
`%notin%` = function(x,y,z) !(x %in% [y & z])
```

Then I called it in the dataframes as following,

```
colnames(new)[colnames(new) %notin% Phlike$V1&DMR$V1 ] <- paste0("UN_", colnames(new)[colnames(new) %notin% Phlike$V1&DMR$V1 ])
```

But it's throwing the following error,

```
Error in colnames(new) %notin% Phlike$V1 : 
  argument "z" is missing, with no default
```

Any suggestion or better solutions would be great

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your dataframes

Comment: I have added the example please see

Comment: Reproducible is achieved with `dput` not `head`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I haven't used dput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can negate the `%in%` then update matching columns:

```
# get the index of non-matching (!) columns
ix <- which(!colnames(new) %in% unique(c(Phlike$V1, DMR$V1)))

# then update with prefix
colnames(new)[ix] <- paste0("UN_", colnames(new)[ix])
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit, idea is intact, apart from they want to lookup from more than 1 dataframe.

Comment: No problem @zx8754 :)

Answer (score 2):

I think one of your problem with the code is that `%notin%` is a function of three parameters and you don't pass it.

I mean, you need to call %notin% function as follows:

`%notin% (colnames(new), Phlike$V1, DMR$V1)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your dataframe, I understand that you have two dataframes you want to check the names from: `Phlike$V1&DMR$V1` and `Phlike$V2&DMR$V1`.

Then you can do

```
`%notin%` = function(x,y) !(x %in% y)
names_to_keep <- c(Phlike$V1&DMR$V1, Phlike$V2&DMR$V1)
colnames(new)[colnames(new) %notin% names_to_keep ] <- paste0("UN_", colnames(new)[colnames(new) %notin% names_to_keep ])
```

Comment: No , its not its of different length ‘&’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: I changed the answer, bu I'm not sure I understood correctly

Comment: ‘&’ not meaningful for factors, this what it throwing when we do names_to_keep. However I found another way to do it, as combing both the data frames as, UNfor <- rbind(DMR ,Phlike) and then applying the same solution as mines